# Resizing images through queues and a worker in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, raspberry-pi

I'm building a website that allows users to upload an image. The image is sent to  my back-end API and is saved with multer.
I'm wondering what is the best way to implement resizing the image on the server after being uploaded to create a thumbnail. That way my website shows a thumbnail and the client won't have to download as much right away through the network.

I imagine the way to do this the best, is to create a queue and each time the server receives an image, I add that to the queue. The worker on its' end, monitors the queue and processes items in it.

I'm not sure what tools to use to do this and I'm kind of at a loss when trying to figure the best way to do it.

Can anyway suggest a way forward, or tools that might put me on track ?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/answers/web-applications/serverless-image-handler/ it's so good.

Comment: I'd like to implement it myself and not use the cloud or any online services for that @ArthurCinader

Comment: That's fair.  The AWS service uses the open source https://github.com/thumbor/thumbor project.  If you want to either figure out how to work that into your own project or build your own version from scratch, it's should be a good place to start.